# OpenCV binary deployment (Linux)

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, x264

In the institute we use Scientific Linux 5 on the cluster and I need to deploy an app that uses a modern OpenCV distribution (2.3.1 or 2.4.0). I don't have root privileges on the cluster.

Essentially, how do I package all the dynamic binary dependencies of ffmpeg (and hopefully x264), opencv so that I can xcopy-deploy my app?

I have a working installation of OpenCV 2.3.1 on Ubuntu. If there was a way to controllably load the executable and copy along all the dynamic dependencies, I could use it.

Thanks,
Vadim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **don't need to install OpenCV** in the computers if you don't have permission to do so.

Place the OpenCV libraries and it's dependencies somewhere in the system and **before** you execute your application make sure you **adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`** to add these paths.

To retrieve the list of dependencies of a certain binary application/library, use `ldd`. You might be interested in reading this post: [Copying shared library dependencies](http://www.h3manth.com/content/copying-shared-library-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

1) **Install GCC 4.7.3**

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install build-essential

---

2) **Install CMake 2.8.10.1**

sudo apt-get install cmake cmake-curses-gui

---

3) **[Download](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.5/opencv-2.4.5.tar.gz) OpenCV 2.4.5**

cd ~/Downloads

tar -xf opencv-2.4.5.tar.gz

cd opencv-2.4.5

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

make -j4

sudo make install

cd ../..

rm -rf opencv-2.4.5*

---

OpenBR uses OpenCV for face recognition. A clear documentation is available to install OpenBR,Here's [the link](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/linux_gcc.html)!